# Do Avocado and Bacon Fat Cancel Out?

Tags: diet, nutrition, food

If I eat avocado and bacon, does the good fat from the avocado cancel out the fat from bacon? pls.

Comment: It would be better to ask that in https://health.stackexchange.com but I'm going to guess absolutely not.

Comment: "Cancel out" in what context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If what you're asking is if, say, you eat 2 strips of bacon which contain 7g of fat and then an avocado which contains 20g of fat, then your body carries on as if it only consumed 13g of avocado fat then no. Fats do not "cancel out" in that sense and the only way to limit negative affects from saturated fats is to consume less of them.